# p:dialog in composite component JS error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, typeerror, composite-component

I am trying to create a composite component to be used in my JSF 2.2 pages. Here is the composite:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<cc:interface componentType="searchUser">
    <!-- Define component attributes here -->
    <cc:attribute name="update" type="java.lang.String"
                  shortDescription="the component to update"/>
    <cc:attribute name="widgetVar" type="java.lang.String"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <p:dialog header="Search for User"
              widgetVar="#{cc.widgetVar}"
              modal="true"
              id="searchDialog"
            >

        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="searchPanel">
            <p:outputLabel value="First Name: "
                           for="firstname"
                    />
            <p:inputText id="firstname" value="#{SearchBean.firstname}"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Last Name: "
                           for="lastname"
                    />
            <p:inputText id="lastname" value="#{SearchBean.lastname}"/>

            <p:commandButton value="search"/>

            <p:dataTable value="#{SearchBean.results}" var="user">
                <p:column headerText="First Name">
                    #{user.firstName}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Last Name">
                    #{user.lastName}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="E-Mail">
                    #{user.email}
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</cc:implementation>
```

and I am using it like:

```
 <my:searchUser update="foo" id="searchDLG" widgetVar="sdgl"/>
 <p:commandButton onclick="PF('sdgl').show();" type="button" value="search for user" />
```

Currently my FacesComponent Java is empty:

```
@FacesComponent("searchUser")
public class searchUser extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

}
```

The target is to create a search form /dialog, wich I can use in multiple locations.

My problem is, that on the click i get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined`.

Any advice on what I am missing would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the right way to reference a composite attribute.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="#{cc.widgetVar}">
```

It's basically referencing a property of the backing component itself.

Composite attributes are available by `#{cc.attrs}` map.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.widgetVar}">
```

The JS error is caused because the actual `widgetVar` value is empty and the `PF('sdgl')` returned [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) on which you're then blindly trying to invoke the `show()` function. It's basically like a `NullPointerException` in Java.

#### See also:

- [Our composite component wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info)
- [Java EE 7 tutorial - Composite Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-advanced-cc.htm)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there are 2 other problems with this composite:

1. The backing component doesn't return the required component family of `UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY`. You can fix it by extending from `UINamingContainer` instead of `UIInput`, or by overriding the `getFamily()` method to return `UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY`.
2. This is not the right purpose of a composite component. There's no single model value at all. I.e. you don't have a `<my:searchUser value="...">` analogous with existing standard components. Rather use an include or tagfile. See also [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen) Otherwise, rework the composite as such that you can ultimately use `<my:searchUser value="#{bean.foundUser}">`.

Comment: Ok i changed a few details: 
1.) moved the command button to the composite component so that it now looks like: `<p:commandButton onclick="PF('sdgl').show();" type="button" value="search for user" />

        <p:dialog header="Search for User"
                  widgetVar="sdgl"
                  modal="true"
                  id="#{cc.clientId}"
                > ...`

and in the xhtml i now have: `<my:searchUser />`  with the result that the commandbutton is not showing. Thaught it would make more sence to to have the button directly in the component

Comment: Is the problem solved where the initial question was about?

Comment: Sorry, I tried it but it did not solve the problem, my guess is, that it is related to the problem in my comment.

Comment: I'm not sure how moving the button is related to fixing the composite attribute referral. Are you saying that you still get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined` after fixing `#{cc.widgetVar}` to `#{cc.attrs.widgetVar}`?

Comment: Yes the error message stays the same. So my guess was that the component is not added to the page/DOM correctly, which is why if I move the command button to the component, it is not displayed at all.

Comment: Ok i was able to identify the problem, and solve it. following your tutorial on your blog, i added `@Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }`

to the FacesComponent, and now it displays the component. (with some minor non question related errors.)